# Stay lain (stay lying down)

Tags: verbs, phrase-choice, irregular-forms

> Stay lain.

Is this correct to mean to stay lying down on your back and to ask somebody to do so?
If not, how to ask someone to keep staying lying down?

Comment: *Stay lain* is technically correct but no one actually says that.  *Stay lying down* is what you should say.

Comment: An American cop would say, 'Freeze!'. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lain** is the perfect form of the verb **to lie**. We use the perfect when an action has been completed in the past. You are describing an action which is still continuing, so you should use the *present continuous*:

> Stay lying down.

The post [What is the Perfect, and How Should I Use It?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/37009) is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

"Lain" is an archaic form, and is hardly ever used in any context.

The most idiomatic ways of expressing this would probably be "don't get up", or "stay on your back", or simply "stay down".

Comment: Really? How would you say "I had lain down" without using this supposedly "archaic" form? How about "We have lain together for weeks"? You would say, perhaps, "We have lied together for weeks"? I've had experiences like that, heaven knows.

Comment: Either "laid down" or "been lying down", depending on intent. I realize there's a slight difference in meaning, but if the distinction mattered, I'd be more inclined to just clarify by using more words (for example, "had laid down and got back up").

Comment: Or *stay as you are*. Or *maintain your position*.

Comment: @duskwuff Dictionary.com has simply " 1. past participle of lie." Where are you finding it referred to as archaic? Do you think _We have lain together for weeks_ and _We have been lying down together for weeks_ are equivalent?

Comment: Perhaps not the strongest source, but [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lain%2Claid%2Clie%2Clay&year_start=1800&year_end=2008) shows it as a *much* rarer word than the other forms of "lie".

Comment: I detest them as fueling a race to the bottom, but if you find them authoritative, this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+lain%2Chave+lied&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20lain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20lied%3B%2Cc0) is much more germane to the OP's question.